# Angular 7 webpack server-side rendering creates ReferenceError: HTMLAnchorElement is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, angular7, server-side-rendering

I have a working website built with angular 7, and I am trying to build it with server-side rendering. Running `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors` is successful, but `node dist/server` produces the following error:

```
/path/to/project/dist/server.js:225854
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
else {}})(this,function(){"use strict";
function b(a,b){return"undefined"==typeof b?b={autoBom:!1}:"object"!=typeof b&&(console.warn("Depricated: Expected third argument to be a object"),b={autoBom:!b}),b.autoBom&&/^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;
.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(a.type)?new Blob(["\uFEFF",a],{type:a.type}):a}function c(b,c,d){var e=new XMLHttpRequest;e.open("GET",b),e.responseType="blob",e.onload=function(){a(e.response,c,d)},e.onerror=function(){console.error("could not download file")},e.send()}function d(a){var b=new XMLHttpRequest;
return b.open("HEAD",a,!1),b.send(),200<=b.status&&299>=b.status}function e(a){try{a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"))}catch(c){var b=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
b.initMouseEvent("click",!0,!0,window,0,0,0,80,20,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),a.dispatchEvent(b)}}var f="object"=

ReferenceError: HTMLAnchorElement is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/dist/server.js:225854:1182)
```

I'm not sure where it is coming from, and there didn't seem to be any other questions that got to the same question. Here is the `server.ts` file I made:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// Fix for window
const domino = require('domino');
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['CSS'] = undefined;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

And here is the `webpack.server.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {  server: './server.ts' },
  mode: 'none',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/,'bufferutil', 'utf-8-validate'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for "WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    ),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin( /uws/ )
  ]
}
```

There is no problem running normal client-side building (e.g. `npm start`). Any suggestions on what might be causing the issue? Any other info that would be helpful?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your code you use `HTMLAnchorElement` as value(i.e. `instanceof HTMLAnchorElement`).

Comment: It actually does not appear anywhere in my code, but rather in a number of dependencies. I'm wondering if there is a way around this other than manually altering those dependencies...

Comment: Find the place where the error happened. And see how you can work around it. For example, add `global['HTMLAnchorElement'] = something` in server.ts

Comment: I've tried setting `global["HTMLAnchorElement"] = win.document.createElement("a");`, but it doesn't seem correct, since I get cascading errors where `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'download' in undefined`.

Comment: Can you create s small repo on github that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @AndrewSchoen Hi! I faced with the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. In my case it is `file-saver` dependency above v2.0.0-rc.4.

Comment: Looks like they have addressed this in the current master.
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/pull/613

Comment: @AndrewSchoen, hi, did you get any solution for this??